# Unable to Import CoolProp

Tags: python, string, import, typeerror, traceback

I am new in programming thing, I just start it yesterday
maybe its very basic

I want to import coolProp to input Cp and Cv value, but when i type:

import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

it shows following messages:

````
```python
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\PythonMatpotlib\Cycles_JupyterNotebook.ipynb Cell 9 line 1
----> 1 import CoolProp
      2 import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

File d:\PythonMatpotlib\first_venv\Lib\site-packages\CoolProp\__init__.py:22
     19 from . import State
     20 from .constants import *
---> 22 __fluids__ = CoolProp.get_global_param_string('fluids_list').split(',')
     23 __incompressibles_pure__ = CoolProp.get_global_param_string('incompressible_list_pure').split(',')
     24 __incompressibles_solution__ = CoolProp.get_global_param_string('incompressible_list_solution').split(',')

File CoolProp.pyx:309, in CoolProp.CoolProp.get_global_param_string()

File stringsource:15, in string.from_py.__pyx_convert_string_from_py_std__in_string()

TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```
````

can you guys help me with this?

I already tried to install and uninstall coolProp, upgrade python version, looking for answer through chat GPT, youtube and website but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The issue relates to Python 3.12. You can resolve it by downgrading to Python 3.11. Another option is manually building of [CoolProp](http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Python/index.html). That worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks maxc900 for the answer...
I downgraded my python to 3.11 already and now my numpy always showing error (cant run)

I tried to downgrade the numpy version as well to 1.25 but its not working

is it also the case for you, after you downgrade python?